# Can't Login into GitHub in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, github

I have cross-checked my password and email several times. It works on the web but not here:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go github
2. Open account window
3. Click settings
4. Click developer settings
5. Click Personal access tokens
6. Click generate new token and then checkout repo, gist and read:org {*present in admin:org*} box afther that
   click the generate token button.
7. Copy created token and then go back android studio github login window and
   click use token
8. Past token then click login

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks, Mate!  I was able to login now 